# Nothing displaying in IE 9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

http://sharan.websitewelcome.com/~meanwhil/
**I've now moved this to a new server: http://www.meanwhile.co.nz/
I'm still seeing the same problems? Can anyone help with this?**

this works okay in firefox 10 and in IE 8 but in IE 9 all I am seeing is one border, thats all.

I'm really struggling to debug this. Any assistance would be appreciated. If you can see an error if you have any recomendations on steps to correct this would be helpful - rather than just telling me that there is an error please :)

The site is based on the latest version of Worpress.

**UPDATE: ***

***it has been suggested that there is a javascript library clash. I have disabled all wordpress plugins, but still I cannot see anything in IE. (see screenshot below)***

***IE is turning on compatibility mode, but even it I turn it off I get the same thing***

***I've tried this on IE 9 on my laptop and my desktop and just see what is shown in the screenshot below. I'm not sure why I see this, yet other people in the comments are saying that they don't have an issue with IE9? (I have IE verson 9.0.8.112.16421, update versions: 9.0.4 (KB261844).***

***I'm quite stuck on what to do to fix this?***

Image attached of what I am seeing - I have cleared my cache and still having this issue.
[image: this is what I'm seeing - just one border!]

Comment: Working fine for me in IE9 and all its compatibility modes.

Comment: Exact duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238056/assistance-needed-to-debug-ie-errors

Comment: It works for me just fine in IE9. Can you post an image of what you're seeing? Try deleting cache.

Comment: I have tried deleting my cache. no joy. i have attached an image of what i am seeing to the post above.

Comment: Your screenshot shows compat mode activated, is the problem still there if you turn compat mode off? Though its fine for me with compat mode on/off, like Kolink says.

Comment: I actually cannot get compatability mode to turn off. if I click it to toggle it off the page just reloads and turns it on again. If I turn it off via the toools menu or via the compatibility mode options it does the same thing - always turning itself back on again????

Comment: try validating the source of that page to make sure. then it seems that you only use jQuery but you are using the `noConflict()`. try removing it.

Comment: Like the others, I don't see the problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Twice I see `<!--//-->`. Could this simple page function without such trick?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring too? comments in my code? can you be more specific about where you see this?

Comment: I saw them as source text in the browser. They should not matter here, but are irritating, as "//" is the JavaScript _begin of line comment_. Probably @elclanrs link provided the error: clashing JS libraries.